# I got a popup on robotics.SE for "chat with an expert". Is that one of you all?

Tags: support

Just now, I was reading answers to a question and an animated box appeared to ask if I wanted to chat with an expert:

[image]

Who are these experts that I can chat with 1-on-1?  Are they members of robotics.SE?  If so, how did they get involved in this system?  And if they aren't on robotics.SE, where does their "expert" title come from?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert

Comment: For posterity, apparently it was an April fool's joke.  Well played.

Answer (score 2):

[image: It looks like you're having trouble looking at a calendar. Would you like some help with that?]

<sup>Courtesy of [Manishearth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174411/138432)</sup>